# condensed if statement errors

Tags: c#, if-statement, beep

Hello I am trying to learn how to write a condensed if statement without the `else{} else if{}` criteria where the code prints YES or NO and plays a tone if criteria are met, I am trying to concatenate this statement.

```
Message = (UserValue == "1 2 3 4") ? "Correct" + Console.Beep(250, 250) : "Incorrect"+ Console.Beep(130, 250);
```

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: Please don't write IF statements in a 'condensed' fashion like this. It doesn't add anything except obscurity and troubles maintaining the code at a later stage. You don't gain **anything**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible as below. Multiple statements in ternary operator are not possible in c# and you can't `+` two different (void and string)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var UserValue = "1 2 3 4";
        var Message = "";
        Message = (UserValue == "1 2 3 4") ? Program.x() : Program.y();
        Console.WriteLine(Message);     
    }

    static Func<string> x = () => {
        Console.Beep(250, 250);
        return "Correct";
    };  


    static Func<string> y = () => {
        Console.Beep(130, 250);
        return "Incorrect";
    };      

}
```

Comment: I thought so, I got it working doing this. using System;

if (UserValue == "1 2 3 4") 
            {
                Console.Beep(250,250);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Beep(130, 250); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Message);
            Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 3):

[Console.Beep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `void`, so you can't concatenate it to a `string`, which is what you are trying to do here:

```
"Correct" + Console.Beep(250, 250)
```

and here:

```
"Incorrect"+ Console.Beep(130, 250)
```

I suggest you use a regular if statement instead, if you want to call `Console.Beep`